# FriendsOfSymfony / FOSUserBundle routing

Tags: symfony

Hy everybody :)
well i installed fosuserbundle and i did all the configurations but when i enter my username and password i get 
 *No route found for "GET /" (from //..../web/app_dev.php/login")*

Well that's my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:    true
        anonymous: true
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My UserBundle/Ressources/config/routing.yml

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
     resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
     prefix: /profile
```

My app/config/routing.yml :

```
sdz_blog:
    resource: "@SdzBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /blog

_user_bundle:
    resource: "@SdzUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Please help me,i tried a lot of times :(

Answer (score 2):

By default, after a successful login, FosUserBundle redirects to `/`. If what you show here are the only routes that you have, then there is no route that will match this pattern since they are all prefixed (with `/blog` for the main ones).

In the command line run `php app/console router:debug` and check if you have any route that matches the pattern `/`.

If not, you can either create one or change the default redirection of FosUserBundle like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main: # or any other firewall name
            form_login:
                default_target_path: # Your route here
```

For more details you can check:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#redirecting-after-login