# Connecting form to FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am having many problems when I want connect to a form in FOSUserBundle. I have this error:

```
No route found for "POST /assets/php/form-process.php" (from "http://localhost/Projet/web/app_dev.php/login")
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

I don't know how to deal with this Exception. Here's my `login_content.html.twig`

```html
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<!-- Page Titile Area -->
<section class="page-title-section section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="title-center">
                    <div class="title-middle">
                        <h2 class="page-tagline">Connexion</h2>
                        <h1 class="page-title">Connexion</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Page Titile Area End -->

<!-- Connexion Section -->
<section class="mea-contact-section section-padding">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="contact-title text-center wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".2s">Page de connexion</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-50">
            <!-- Section Titile -->
            <div class="col-md-6 contact-widget-section2 wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                <h2>Pas encore inscrit?</h2>
                <div class="find-widget">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE90F;</i> Nous vous invitons à vous inscrire afin de passer vos commande
                </div>
                <div class="form-submit mt-20">
                    <a class="btn btn-common" href="{{path('fos_user_registration_register')}}" id="_submit" id="form-submit"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C9;</i> S'inscrire</a>
                    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 hidden"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div><br> 
                
                <div class="find-widget">
                    <a href="{{path('fos_user_resetting_request')}}"> Mot de passe perdu?</a>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <!-- contact form -->
            <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" class="shake" role="form" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contact-form" data-toggle="validator">
                    {% if csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                    {% endif %}
                    <!-- email -->
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email or User name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="form-control" required data-error="Please enter your Email or username"/>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Subject -->
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                      <label class="control-label" for="msgSubject">Pass word</label>
                      <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="_password" required data-error="Please enter your pass word" />
                      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Form Submit -->
                    <div class="form-submit mt-20">
                        <button class="btn btn-common" type="submit" id="_submit" id="form-submit"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C9;</i> Se connecter</button>
                        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Please help me

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi to you I have a problem with my FOSUserBundle Bundle, when when a user try to connect I get an error                                                                     No route found for "POST /assets/php/form-process.php" (from "http://localhost/Projet/web/app_dev.php/login")
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427616/friendsofsymfony-fosuserbundle-routing

Comment: Hi sakhunzai, I have this error against. I send you capture of picture to that error. this is my security.yml                                                                              `    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:      ^/
            anonymous:    true
            provider:     main
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path:            /`

Comment: delete your answer and add that to your question unless your are self-answering

Comment: It seems you done have routes defined for the login action

Comment: check this http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc to override routes if you are defining new ones otherwise you need to enable routes and read this https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html